# Spacing words in a text file with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently having a hard time separating words on a txt document
with regex into a list, I have tried ".split" and ".readlines" my document
consists of words like "HelloPleaseHelpMeUnderstand" the words are
capitalized but not spaced so I'm at a loss on how to get them into a list.
this is what I have currently but it only returns a single word.

```
import re
file1 = open("file.txt","r")
strData = file1.readline()
listWords = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+", strData)
print(listWords)
```

one of my goals for doing this is to search for another word within the elements of the list, but i just wish to know how to list them so i may continue my work.

if anyone can guide me to a solution I would be grateful.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[a-z]*", strData)`

Comment: unfortunately, this gives the same result.

Comment: Are you sure? Check https://ideone.com/ysoVxS

Comment: I was able to get a copy paste of your code to work separately, but when implemented with the txt file I'm using it persists to only give the first word. could this be because the txt file has too many words mashed together?

Comment: So post the whole code that fails into the question. BTW, to read all file into a variable, you need `strData = file1.read()`

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely overlooked the strData = file1.read() error that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular regex based on lookarounds **to insert spaces between glued letter words** is

```
import re
text = "HelloPleaseHelpMeUnderstand"
print( re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ", text) )
# => Hello Please Help Me Understand
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vglrB2/1). Note adjustments will be necessary to account for numbers, or single letter uppercase words like `I`, `A`, etc.

Regarding your current code, you need to make sure you read the whole file into a variable (using `file1.read()`, you are reading just the first line with `readline()`) and use a `[A-Z]+[a-z]*` regex to match all the words glued the way you show:

```
import re
with open("file.txt","r") as file1:
    strData = file1.read()
    listWords = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[a-z]*", strData)
    print(listWords)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ysoVxS)

**Pattern details**

- `[A-Z]+` - one or more uppercase letters
- `[a-z]*` - zero or more lowercase letters.

Comment: @ Wiktor , nice & simple .. +1

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import re
strData = """HelloPleaseHelpMeUnderstand
And here not in
HereIn"""
listWords = re.findall(r"(([A-Z][a-z]+){2,})", strData)
result = [i[0] for i in listWords]
print(result)
# ['HelloPleaseHelpMeUnderstand', 'HereIn']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(re.sub(r"\B([A-Z])", r" \1", "DoIThinkThisIsABetterAnswer?"))
```

Do i Think This Is A Better Answer?